# Create a Secure Random number in iOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, cryptography, swift4

```
public func createSecureRandomKey(numberOfBits: Int) -> Any {
    let attributes: [String: Any] =
        [kSecAttrKeyType as String:CFString.self,
         kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:numberOfBits]

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else {
        return ""
    }
    return privateKey
}
```

I am trying to create Secure random number like above way, but returning nothing, Could any one please help me. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried printing `error`?

Comment: Yes.. But No error displyed, always going to return ""

Comment: Add `print(error)` inside the `guard`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the wrong function. With your function you are generating a new key. But as your title says you want to generate secure random numbers.
For this there is a function called: **SecRandomCopyBytes(*:*:_:)**

Here is a code snippet taken from the official apple documentation how to use it:

```
var bytes = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 10)
let status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytes.count, &bytes)

if status == errSecSuccess { // Always test the status.
    print(bytes)
    // Prints something different every time you run.
}
```

Source: [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes)