# What is the meaning of CFString.self?

Tags: swift, keyword, self

I've seen the Q/A [here about the `self` keyword in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26835013/589259).

However, to me this doesn't explain the use of `.self` in the following code fragment from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50746833/589259)

```
let attributes: [String: Any] =
    [kSecAttrKeyType as String:CFString.self,
     kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:numberOfBits]
```

What does `self` do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type.self` is the type as a value.

There is a difference between

```
let s : String = "hello world"
```

where String is declaring the type of `s`, and

```
let sometype : Any = String.self
```

where we are assigning the String type itself as the *value* to be stored. That's called the *metatype*.

Comment: And of course there are always the docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455

Comment: Am I correct to assume these are considered "[Postfix Self Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID401)"?